# nested select query in elasticsearch

Tags: sql, select, elasticsearch

I have to convert the following query in elasticsearch :

```
select * from index where observable not in (select observable from index where tags = 'whitelist')
```

I read that I should use a Filter in a Not Filter but I don't understand how to do.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

EDIT:

I have to get all except those that have 'whitelist' tag but I need to check also that nothing of the blacklist element is contained into the whitelist.

Comment: Are u selecting from the same index ?

Comment: the your query should be simplified like this 
select * from index where tags <>'whitelist'

Comment: then...what api are u using for elasticsearch ?

Comment: Yes I know but I need to check this : if a element contained with tag 'whitelist' is also present with tag <> of 'whitelist' then I'll have to exclude that.

Comment: I'm using laravel with elasticsearch API

Comment: hmmm so i guess you can have same element multiple times with different values right ?

Comment: Yes, here an example: observable => 'google.it', tags => 'whitelist' ; observable => 'google.it', tags => 'malware' . So I have to exclude the first and check if the observable value is also present in different tag then exclude also the second.

Comment: ok i get it. is the index size big ?

Comment: Yes, like 250k results.. I tried to get all results and compare but it's too slow

Comment: so if you do this ... select distinct Observable from Index where tags = 'whitelist' you will get how many records ?

Comment: I don't have a sql database, I have to do in ES but I don't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query can be simplified to this:

```
select * from index where tags not in ('whitelist')
```

As a result the "corresponding" ES query would be

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "terms": {
              "tags": [
                "whitelist"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

or another using the `not` filter instead of `bool/must_not`:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "not": {
          "terms": {
            "tags": [
              "whitelist"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply.. I have to get all except those that have 'whitelist' tag but I need to check also that nothing of the blacklist element is contained into the whitelist. So I guess that query couldn't be semplified

Comment: Hmmm... I think the best would be to provide a sample table with 3-4 records to highlight what your query does.