# how to query fieldA=fieldB in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I want to query similary follow's SQL :

```
select * from talbe where id=cityid
```

Who know how to implement in es ?

thanks for your answer !

Comment: duplicate question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615142/nested-select-query-in-elasticsearch

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539447/nested-sql-select-using-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) like this:

```
POST /table/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.id.value == doc.cityid.value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Only numeric fields may be accessed，Do you have any other way ?

Comment: my id and cityid is string

Comment: have you tried the script? `==` in groovy is like `equals`  in Java

Comment: thanks @Val , i need time to study how to use groovy in es, if sucess, i can   update this problem status ,thanks again !

Comment: You simply need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in `elasticsearch.yml`, restart ES and that's it.

Comment: thanks @Val  please help me answer my new problem ,thanks for you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050031/how-to-implement-follow-sql-in-es