# how to implement the following sql query in es?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I want to query similarly the following SQL query:

```
select countryName, count( distinct(countryId) ) as findCount   from city group by countryName having findCount > 1
```

Who know how to implement in es ?

thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do this with a `terms` aggregation with `min_doc_count: 2` like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "countries": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "countryName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ids": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "countryId",
            "min_doc_count": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the `countryName` field should be `not_analyzed` in order for this to work, or the `countryName` field is a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) with a `not_analyzed` part.

Comment: i have a count( distinct(countryId) )  function ,it seems need pipeline agge to having filter count

Comment: There's a 1:1 relationship between countryId and countryName right? so `count(distinct(countryId)) == count(distinct(countryName))` right?

Comment: my data count(distinct(countryId)) != count(distinct(countryName)) , so maybe use min_doc_count  is  incorrect

Comment: So as I understand you have the same country name which can have different country ids? That's funny, but ok, I'll update my answer

Comment: min_doc_count   instead   min_doc_size can execute